# How can I stop my wpf animation

Tags: wpf

I create an animation like this:

```
private DoubleAnimation BusyGettingNewOrders = new DoubleAnimation(40, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

And start it with this.

```
BusyGettingNewOrders.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1000);
BusyGettingNewOrders.To = 40;
BusyGettingNewOrders.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
GetNewOrdersImage.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, BusyGettingNewOrders);
```

I need to stop it after a long running process ends.  I tried the following, but although it executes, it has no effect.  The animation continues to run.

```
BusyGettingNewOrders.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);
```

Ideas?

Comment: Try `GetNewOrdersImage.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, null)`

Comment: @Clemens.  That did it friend.  Thanks.  If you want to add that as an answer, I'll put  a green check on it.  : - )

Comment: ... also, that worked as a solution even when I start the animation with RepeatBehavior.Forever